# Regexp match the output , while it shouldn't

Tags: tcl, regexp-replace

my output looks like this :

```
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| id   | IP address   | status  | type       | created at            |
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| sc-1 |              | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
| sc-2 | 164.54.39.30 | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
```

I need to check if sc-1and sc2 are "runnig".

My solution for the first row is following:

```
proc check_if_exist_in_output{lines    
String_to_Check} {
set err_msg ""
set Flag "False"
foreach line $lines { if { $line eq $String_to_Check} {
                    set Flag "True"
        return $Flag }}
if {$Flag == "False"} {return "Error"}
```

Now this is working fine, but the thing is, that I may have this IP also in the first line , and then my script doesn't work .

So I tries a solution with REGEXP , I want to provide a line from the output, and to check if it contains the line I am looking for.

long story short : 
if   `"| sc-2 |              | running |"     is part of line    " | sc-2 | 164.54.39.30 | running | "`
The answer should be true.

my new proc with REXEXP looks like this :

```
proc check_if_exist_in_output_with_reg_exspression {lines Str} { 
            set Flag "False"
    foreach line $lines {if {[regexp "$line.*" $Str] == 1}{                         
                      set Flag "True"
                  return $Flag }}
    if {$Flag == "False"} {
    #FAil step
    "Retuen Error" 
    }
}

#calling the proc:
set lines [split $OutPut "\n"]
set expected_output "| sc-2 |              | running |"
set Result [check_if_exist_in_output_reg $lines $expected_output]
```

But the above proc always returns TRUE, doesn't meter what I send it.
  While I expect to get False in case the line doesn't really exist. 
  I also though about sending the expected result as something like :

```
    set expected_output "| sc-2 |[regexp {(?:\d+\.){3}\d+}]| running |"
```

But I am not sure how to write it in the correct way.

Comment: You've made your regex fairly difficult.  Is there ever a case where `^.*sc-2.*running.*$` is insufficient?

Comment: hmm , didnt think of it. I guess it good.

Comment: thank's it solved and simplified everything

Comment: The problem with your code is that the regex you send to the proc is not just a string, it contains the regex special character `|`. So you are testing if `$Str` contains the empty string OR " sc-2 " OR a sequence of spaces OR " running " OR the empty string again. And since every string contains the empty string, the result is always true.

Answer (score 0):

as was suggested by jasonmclose (I am not sure on how to tag here) .
I 've changed the regexp to amore simple one . and the proc is working just fine like this  :

```
    proc check_if_exist_in_output_with_reg_exspression {lines String_to_Check} {
    set err_msg ""
    set Flag "False"
    foreach line $lines {  if {[regexp ^.*sc-2.*running.* $String_to_Check ]==1} {
                          set Flag "True"
                          return $Flag }}
    if {$Flag == "False"} {
    #Fail step
    return "Error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the OP's question on getting the regexp right, but it is worth mentioning that the whole fuzz can also be tackled without a regexp. You may want to consider sth. along the lines of:

```
set data {
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| id   | IP address   | status  | type       | created at            |
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| sc-1 |              | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
| sc-2 | 164.54.39.30 | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
}

set status [dict create]
foreach line [lrange [split [string trim $data] "\n"] 3 end-1] {
    set line [lmap el [split [string trim $line |] |] {string trim $el}]
    dict set status [lindex $line 0] [lindex $line 2]
}

puts [dict get $status "sc-2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            set Output {+------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
            | id   | IP address   | status  | type       | created at            |
            +------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
            | sc-1 |              | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
            | sc-2 | 164.54.39.30 | running | r4.2       | Aug 21, 2017 08:09:44 |
            +------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------------------+};

            proc check_if_exist_in_output_reg {lines Str} { 
                        set Flag "False"
                        if {[regexp  -linestop $Str $lines a] ==1} { ; #-linestop for matching whithin a line, a for just storing match in a variable a
                            #puts $a
                            set Flag "True"
                            return $Flag 
                        } else {
                            return "Error"
                        }
            }

            #calling the proc:
            #set lines [split $Output "\n"] : not needed
            set expected_output {sc-1.*running} ; #brackets for literal substitution
            set Result [check_if_exist_in_output_reg $Output $expected_output] 
            puts $Result
```